# ViewPagerIndicator doesn't show underline in Tab (Help)

Tags: android, tabs, viewpagerindicator, underline

I want to make simple TabPagerIndicator, but It doesn't show a underline, I use xml to change the style. This is my xml style file:

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="vpiTitlePageIndicatorStyle">@style/CustomTitlePageIndicator</item>
    <item name="vpiUnderlinePageIndicatorStyle">@style/CustomUnderlinePageIndicator</item> 
    <item name="vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle">@style/CustomTabPageIndicator</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTabPageIndicator" parent="Widget.TabPageIndicator">
    <item name="android:background">@color/fondo_activity</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/CustomTabPageIndicator.Text</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF555555</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:dividerPadding">10dp</item>
    <item name="showDividers">middle</item> 
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:fadingEdge">horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:fadingEdgeLength">8dp</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTabPageIndicator.Text" parent="android:TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomUnderlinePageIndicator">
    <item name="selectedColor">#FFCC0000</item>
    <item name="android:background">#FFCCCCCC</item>
    <item name="fadeLength">1000</item>
    <item name="fadeDelay">1000</item>
</style>


<style name="CustomTitlePageIndicator">
    <item name="android:background">#18FF0000</item>
    <item name="footerColor">#FFAA2222</item>
    <item name="footerLineHeight">1dp</item>
    <item name="footerIndicatorHeight">3dp</item>
    <item name="footerIndicatorStyle">underline</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#AA000000</item>
    <item name="selectedColor">#FF000000</item>
    <item name="selectedBold">true</item>
</style>
```

In this picture you can see how it is shown (the red line on the top is part of the action bar)
[image]

Does anyone knows where is the error and How can I solve it?

Best.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate on where exactly you want to show the underline? Do you mean a vertical line between FOTOS and VIDEOS? Since I was not able to understand your question properly. Still I try to answer.

If you want something like (  FOTOS | VIDEOS  ) then you have to put

`<item name="android:divider">@drawable/custom_tab_indicator_divider</item>`

custom_tab_indicator_divider is basically a nine patch image. You can checkout the nine patch in the source code of viewpagerindicator library.

If you want something like **__________** below the FOTO and VIDEOS.You can create a selector and set it to background like

`<item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_tab_indicator</item>`

Check vpi_tab_indicator.xml in the library project for more info.